# Show dialog on back pressed inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I've an activity and inside it a fragment.
What's the right procedure to ask for saving data (via a dialog) before exiting the activity?

1. User press back
2. Activity notify the fragment via interface onBackPressed
3. Fragment show dialog where user can choose to save/unsave data
4. User choose an option in the dialog
5. Fragment notify activity that calls super.onBackpressed()?

I'm not sure about point 5, because at point 2. I've to avoid default behaviour, instead at 5. I've to call super.
I need to mantain the save business logic inside the fragment.

P.S. the result is something like when FB app ask you on exit, to save or delete a post that is still a draft.

Comment: post your callback to the activity and your onBackPressed method of the relevant activity

Answer (score 0):

What you described works. Alternatively, for step 5, you can simply do

```
getActivity().finish;
```

if the user confirms exiting.

Comment: Thanks I was just wondering about finish and backpressed differences.

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreateView() of the fragment, right before you return the view, add a listener to it:

```
v.setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
                           //do your stuff
                    }
                    return false;
                }
          });

        return v;
```